# material-ui : Uncaught Invariant Violation: traverseParentPath

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a search TextField in my AppBar that I am dynamically loading on certain pages.  If a component loads in my "MainView" that is a list that requires searching, the component can dynamically tell the search box to display via the ComponentWillMount.  That component also needs to hide the search box on UnMount.  However, whenever I unmount the search box component, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: traverseParentPath(...): Cannot traverse from and to the same ID, ``.

Here is the code that displays the text search:  'header' is defined above in the render method, it just calls a redux state prop.

```
    <AppBar
            title={this.props.title}
            onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle.bind(this)}
            iconElementRight={
                <div>
                {header.showSearch
                ?
                  <TextField onChange={this.updateSearchText.bind(this)}
                  id="header_search"
                  hintText="Search..."/>
                : ''}
                  <IconMenu
                    iconButtonElement={
                       <IconButton><NavigationMoreVert /></IconButton>
                    }
                    targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
                    anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom'}}
                  >                        
                    <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" onTouchTap={this.logoutUser.bind(this)} leftIcon={<ActionExitToApp />} />
                  </IconMenu>
              </div>
        }
        />
```

If I comment out the TextField, I never receive the error.  Also, if I don't unmount it I don't receive the error.

Any ideas?

Update: This is with 0.15.0-alpha.2 release of material-ui.  I can confirm this error does not happen in version 14.4.

Comment: Try changing the `id="header_search"` to `ref="header_search"`. React likes to own the ids.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work.  I still get the same error.